# How to proceed coroutine work if object state was changed?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I try to create an android game on pure kotlin, but I stacked on the bullet move rendering. If I do single shoot and will waiting that it disappear it works well, but if I moves player and do the next one shoot, previous shoot freeze on their position and doesn't finish their rendering. It looks like this:

[image]

On the picture: shooted once, moved left on the one point and do another shoot

Seems that the problem is in my drawShoot method. If the player position changed , that shoot position changed too, but I expect that coroutines will solved my problem, but it's isn't. Here is my code, any ideas hot to fix the bug?

Here is my code :

```
class GameV2 {


    companion object {
        private const val BLANK_CHAR = "  "
        private const val BLANK_CHAR_CODE = 0
        private const val AREA_BORDER_CHAR = "x"
        private const val AREA_BORDER_CHAR_CODE = 1
        private const val PLAYER_ONE = "^"
        private const val PLAYER_ONE_CODE = 2
        private const val SHOOT = "o"
        private const val SHOOT_CODE = 3
        private var gameFinished = false
        lateinit var gameAreaWidth: Number
        lateinit var gameAreaHeigth: Number

        private var gameArea = Array(0) { IntArray(0) }
        private val observer = GameStateObserver()
        private val gameState = GameState()

        var shootPositionY: Int = 0
        var shootPositionX: Int = 0
        var playerPositionX: Int = 0
        var playerPositionY: Int = 0

        var bulletPlayerOnePositionX: Int = 0
        var bulletPlayerOnePositionY: Int = 0

        var bulletPlayerTwoPositionY: Int = 0
        var bulletPlayerTwoPositionX: Int = 0

        fun prepareGameEngine() {
            observer.addObserver(gameState)
            observer.changeState()
        }

        fun initGameArea(x: Int, y: Int) {
            gameAreaWidth = y
            gameAreaHeigth = x
            gameArea = Array(x) { IntArray(y) }
            var i = 1
            var j: Int

            while (i <= x) {
                j = 1
                while (j <= y) {
                    if (i == 1 || i == x || j == 1 || j == y) {
                        gameArea[i - 1][j - 1] = 1
                    } else {
                        gameArea[i - 1][j - 1] = 0
                    }
                    j++
                }
                i++
            }

        }

        fun drawGameArea(): String {
            val sb = StringBuffer()
            gameArea.forEach { i ->
                //println()
                sb.append("\n")
                i.forEach { j ->
                    if (j == BLANK_CHAR_CODE) {
                        //      print(BLANK_CHAR)
                        sb.append(BLANK_CHAR)
                    }
                    if (j == AREA_BORDER_CHAR_CODE) {
                        //    print(AREA_BORDER_CHAR)
                        sb.append(AREA_BORDER_CHAR)
                    }
                    if (j == PLAYER_ONE_CODE) {
                        //    print(PLAYER_ONE)
                        sb.append(PLAYER_ONE)
                    }
                    if (j == SHOOT_CODE) {
                        //    print(SHOOT)
                        sb.append(SHOOT)
                    }
                }
            }
            return sb.toString()
        }

        private fun clearGameAreaSpaceInCoords(x: Int, y: Int) {
            gameArea[x][y] = BLANK_CHAR_CODE
        }

        fun updateUserPosition(x: Int, y: Int) {
            playerPositionX = x
            playerPositionY = y

            gameArea[playerPositionX][playerPositionY] = PLAYER_ONE_CODE
            observer.changeState()
        }

        fun moveUserRight() {
            if (playerPositionY < gameAreaWidth.toInt() - 2) {
                // example: y - 1 = move left; x - 1  = move up
                clearGameAreaSpaceInCoords(playerPositionX, playerPositionY)
                updateUserPosition(playerPositionX, playerPositionY + 1)
            }
        }

        fun moveUserLeft() {
            if (playerPositionY > 1) {
                clearGameAreaSpaceInCoords(playerPositionX, playerPositionY)
                updateUserPosition(playerPositionX, playerPositionY - 1)
            }
        }

        fun drawShoot() {
            // playerPositionX - 1 mean that 1 point higher than player character
            shootPositionY = playerPositionY
            shootPositionX = playerPositionX
            GlobalScope.launch { // launch a new coroutine in background and continue
                for(i in 1..gameAreaHeigth.toInt() - 3 ){
                    gameArea[shootPositionX - i][shootPositionY] = SHOOT_CODE
                    observer.changeState()
                    delay(300L)
                    clearGameAreaSpaceInCoords(shootPositionX - i, shootPositionY)
                    observer.changeState()
                }
            }
        }

        private fun isGameStateChanged(): Boolean {
            return GameStateObserver().hasChanged()
        }

        fun startGame() {

        }


    }
}
```

SOLVED. Solution : It's my bad. I call global variable inside drawShoot method. All what i need it's change global var to local, like this:

```
fun drawPlayerOneShoot() {
        // playerOnePositionX - 1 mean that 1 point higher than player character
        val shootPositionY = playerOnePositionY
        val shootPositionX = playerOnePositionX
        // launch a new coroutine in background and continue
        GlobalScope.launch {
            for(i in 1..gameAreaHeigth.toInt() - 3 ){
                gameArea[shootPositionX - i][shootPositionY] = SHOOT_CODE
                observer.changeState()
                delay(300L)
                clearGameAreaSpaceInCoords(shootPositionX - i, shootPositionY)
                if (shootPositionX - i == playerTwoPositionX && shootPositionY == playerOnePositionY){
                    isPlayerOneWin = true
                    println("PLAYER ONE WIN")
                }
                observer.changeState()
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

From the first glimpse it seems that the problem lies not in the Coroutine itself, but inside of observer.changeState() . What kind of code is there? I guess it uses a singular "shot" instance and it does not matter whether you launch a new coroutine to change it.